# Efficient smart pointer implementation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, pointers, boost

The idea behind this is mainly educational but I might even consider using it in reality if turns out to be good. Here's my first try at implementing smart pointers:

```
template<typename T>
class smart_pointer{
    T* pointer;
    std::size_t *refs;

    void clear(){
        if (!--*refs){
            delete pointer;
            delete refs;
        }
    }

public:
    smart_pointer(T* p = NULL)
        : pointer(p), refs(new std::size_t(1))
    {}
    smart_pointer(const smart_pointer<T>& other)
        : pointer(other.pointer), refs(other.refs)
    {
        ++*refs;
    }
    ~smart_pointer(){
        clear();
    }

    smart_pointer<T>& operator=(const smart_pointer<T>& other){
        if (this != &other){
            clear();

            pointer = other.pointer;
            refs    = other.refs;
            ++*refs;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    smart_pointer<T>& operator=(T* p){
        if (pointer != p){
            pointer = p;
            *refs = 1;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*(){
        return *pointer;
    }

    const T& operator*() const{
        return *pointer;
    }

    T* operator->(){
        return pointer;
    }

    const T* operator->() const{
        return pointer;
    }

    std::size_t getCounts(){
        return *refs;
    }
};
```

I have tested this under valrind and its clean. Also, to see how much the "smartness" makes things slower, I did the following test:

```
struct foo{
    int a;
};

template<typename pointer_t>
class bar{
    pointer_t f_;

public:
    bar(foo *f)
        :f_(f)
    {}

    void set(int a){
        f_->a = a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo *f = new foo;

    typedef smart_pointer<foo> ptr_t;
//    typedef boost::shared_ptr<foo> ptr_t;
//    typedef foo* ptr_t;

    bar<ptr_t> b(f);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<300000000; ++i)
        b.set(i);

//    delete f;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is some timing between my implementation, boost, and raw pointers: (code compiled with `clang++ -O3`)

```
typedef smart_pointer<foo> ptr_t;

real   0m0.006s
user   0m0.001s
sys    0m0.002s

typedef boost::shared_ptr<foo> ptr_t;

real    0m0.336s
user    0m0.332s
sys     0m0.002s

typedef foo* ptr_t;

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```

My implementation seems to be running almost as fast as raw pointers, which I think is a good sign.  What worries me here is why Boost is running slower.  Have I missed something in my implementation that is important and I might get into trouble for later?

Comment: I have a question regarding incrementing the count. what if the smart pointer sp was originally pointed to something else, and you do a sp=sp1. In this case you need to decrease the old count first.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> So the idea behind this is mainly educational...

Cool. Always good to try and understand how things work under the covers.

> ...but I might even consider using it in reality if turns out to be good.

Please rethink this. Smart pointer implementations are **incredibly** difficult to get right. Scott Myers, of *Effective C++* fame, famously tried to implement a `shared_ptr`. After feedback from something like 10 iterations, it was **still wrong**.

Let's go through a few things here.

```
smart_pointer(T* p = NULL)
  : pointer(p), refs(new std::size_t(1))
```

This constructor should be `explicit` to avoid implicit type conversions through construction.

Your `operator=(T* p)` leaks. Here's a small example:

```
int main()
{
    int *x = new int(5);
    {
        smart_pointer<int> sp(x);
        sp = new int(6);
    } // sp destroyed here 

    std::cout << *x << "\n"; // This should have been deleted but wasn't
}
```

To convince yourself that this is the case, modify your `clear()` method:

```
void clear(){
    if (!--*refs){
        std::cout << "deleteting " << *pointer << " at " << pointer << "\n";
        delete pointer;
        delete refs;
    }
}
```

This will print out "deleting 6 at `<some memory address>`".

Here's just a small rundown of what `boost::shared_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr`) provides that is missing here:

- Constructors allowing a `Deleter`, which is used instead of a raw `delete`.
- Constructor allowing construction from `<template Tp1> shared_ptr(Tp1 * ...)` where `Tp1` is convertible to type `T`.
- Copy constructor allowing construction from a `shared_ptr` with convertible template type `<T1>`.
- Copy constructor taking `weak_ptr`, `unique_ptr`.
- Move constructor and assignment operator.
- Usage of `nothrow` where it is required to be.
- `reset`, which will replace the currently managed object.
- All the non-member operators like `operator<`, `operator==`, etc that allow containers and algorithms to work correctly. For example, `std::set` will not work correctly with your pointer class, neither will things like `std::sort`.
- A specialization of `std::swap`.
- A specialization of `std::hash`. Your pointer class won't work correctly with `std::unordered_set` or `std::unordered_map`.
- explicit operator bool conversion for `nullptr` tests, so that one can write `if (<some_shared_ptr>) { ... }`.
- Utility functions like `std::make_shared` which you should pretty much always use when creating a `shared_ptr`.

The big pain point, and the reason why `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` will be slower is the fact that they are thread-safe. Your `smart_ptr` when accessed by multiple threads could very easily delete the pointer it holds before another class is done with it, leading to dereferencing of a `delete`d object, and thus undefined behaviour. Furthermore, all of the `atomic` operations are specialized for `shared_ptr`.

The above is not an exhaustive list.

I don't write this to discourage you, but merely to try and reinforce the fact that writing something like this is a lot of work. It is very technical, and really, really easy to get wrong. In terms of the standard library, `shared_ptr` may be one of the most difficult things to write correctly.

Comment: I think we should hold an "everyone write a shared pointer day".

Comment: I would like to add that OP's implementation allocates the reference counter on the heap separately from the subject data. This can (if used very frequently) be a source of memory fragmentation, it is generally good to avoid small heap allocations not to mention the overhead of allocating 4 bytes is like 32 bytes or something. Also if the subject data and reference counter would be allocated together in a struct one would get better data locality and improved cache behavior. These two reasons are the reasons why std::make_shared<>() exists and is preferred for creation of smart pointers.