# Smart Pointers with Reference Counting - C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to improve my general skills in C++ so I plan to write versions of shared_ptr and unique_ptr from scratch. I wrote a version of shared_ptr with reference counting and I was wondering for reviews.

```
#ifndef __SHIVA_XSMARTPTRS__
#define __SHIVA_XSMARTPTRS__

/*
This tries to define a reference counted smart pointer class instead of
regular pointers
*/

namespace Shiva
{
template <class T>
class SmartPtr
{
  public:
    //Default Constructor
    explicit SmartPtr(T* p = 0)
    {
      if(p)
        ptrWrapper_ = new PointerWrapper(p,1);
      else
        ptrWrapper_ = new PointerWrapper();
    }

    //The copy constructor
    SmartPtr(const SmartPtr& copyObj)
    {
      ptrWrapper_ = copyObj->ptrWrapper_;
      ptrWrapper_->incrementRefCount();
    }

    //Assignment operator
    SmartPtr& operator=(const SmartPtr& copyObj)
    {
      if(this != copyObj)
      {
        //Decrement and decimate as needed
        unsigned int preReleaseRefCount = ptrWrapper_->getRefCount();
        ptrWrapper_->decrementRefCount();
        if(preReleaseRefCount==1)
        {
          delete ptrWrapper_;
          ptrWrapper_ = 0;
        }
        ptrWrapper_ = copyObj->ptrWrapper_;
        ptrWrapper_->incrementRefCount();
      }
      return *this;
    }

    //The main object destructor
    //Essentially decrement the refcount by 1. If the refcount is equal to 0, then you should delete the pointer
    ~SmartPtr()
    {
      unsigned int preReleaseRefCount = ptrWrapper_->getRefCount();
      ptrWrapper_->decrementRefCount();
      if(preReleaseRefCount==1)
      {
        delete ptrWrapper_;
        ptrWrapper_ = 0;
      }
    }

    //Referncing operator
    T& operator*()
    {
      return ptrWrapper_->getReference();
    }

    //Address operator
    T* operator->()
    {
      return ptrWrapper_->getPointer();
    }

    //Get reference counter
    int getRefCount() const
    {
      return ptrWrapper_->getRefCount();
    }

    //Is this the only copy of the object present
    bool unique() const
    {
      return ptrWrapper_->isUnique();
    }

private:
    class PointerWrapper
    {
    public:
      PointerWrapper(T* ptr=0, int refCount = 0)
      :ptr_(ptr),refCount_(refCount)
      {}

      T* getPointer()
      {
        return ptr_;
      }

      T& getReference()
      {
        return *ptr_;
      }

      unsigned int getRefCount()
      {
        return refCount_;
      }

      void decrementRefCount()
      {
        refCount_--;
        if(!refCount_)
        {
          delete ptr_;
          ptr_ = 0;
        }
      }

      void incrementRefCount()
      {
        refCount_++;
      }

      bool isUnique()
      {
        return (refCount_==1);
      }

    private:
      T* ptr_;
      int refCount_;
    };

    PointerWrapper* ptrWrapper_;
};
}

#endif
```

Comment: Please read the first two points of [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/26356/93301).

Comment: IT's a lot harder than you think.

Answer (score 1):

### Review

#### Issue

My first issues is that using your shared pointer is not safe. Once I give you the pointer. You are responsible for deleting it **all** situations (especially when exceptions happen).

But if the call to `new PointerWrapper(p, 1)` fails. ie it throws BadAlloc then you will leak my object. So you need to watch out for that allocation and delete the pointer immediately if you throw.

#### Missing Feature

You have not implemented move semantics. This is absolutely essential.

Your object is missing a swap function.

#### Design

I don't think the class `PointerWrapper` buys you ay functionality or makes the code any easier to write.

#### nullptr

Prefer to use `nullptr` over `0` as the non existing pointer. `0` is a number and can easily be converted to other things when you least expect it. `nullptr` of `std::nullptr_t` and can only be assigned to pointers and is not auto converted into other things.

#### General grumbles

I think the assignment operator is overly complex. It would be much simpler to write this as using the standard copy and swap idiom.

```
    SmartPtr& operator=(const SmartPtr& copyObj)
    {
         SmartPtr  copy(copyObj);
         copy.swap(*this);
         return *this;
    }
```

This logic seems a bit overly complex.

```
        unsigned int preReleaseRefCount = ptrWrapper_->getRefCount();
        ptrWrapper_->decrementRefCount();
        if(preReleaseRefCount==1)
        {
          delete ptrWrapper_;
          ptrWrapper_ = 0;
        }
```

Personally I would have got `decrementRefCount()` to return true if it deleted the object.

```
        if (ptrWrapper_->decrementRefCount())
        {
          delete ptrWrapper_;
        }
```

No point in setting the `ptrWrapper_` to `nullptr`

```
           ptrWrapper_ = 0;
```

When the very next statement sets it to another value.

```
        ptrWrapper_ = copyObj->ptrWrapper_;
```

#### Self Plug

These articles are a good read (I wrote them):

[Unique Ptr](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2014/12/30/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer/)
[Shared Ptr](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/15/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-ii/)
[Constructor](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/23/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-iii/)